# Group_by / summarise statement not working with multiple statements

Tags: r, dplyr

Why isn't this working?

```
 me_totals_by_county <- me %>%
  group_by(redcap_data_access_group)%>%
  summarise(
            (alcohol_number_occurences = sum(grepl('alcohol', me_cause, ignore.case = TRUE) | grepl('ethanol', me_cause, ignore.case = TRUE))),
            (fentanyl_number_occurences = sum(grepl('alcohol', me_cause, ignore.case = TRUE)))
            )
me_totals_by_county
```

It doesn't give any error, but it fails to produce the expected output:

```
       redcap_data_access_group `(...)`
   <chr>                      <int>
 1 c1                             0
 2 c2                             0
 3 c3                             1
 4 c4                             0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a couple of extra opening parentheses. Try this:

```
 me_totals_by_county <- me %>%
  group_by(redcap_data_access_group)%>%
  summarise(
            alcohol_number_occurences = sum(grepl('alcohol', me_cause, ignore.case = TRUE) | grepl('ethanol', me_cause, ignore.case = TRUE))),
            fentanyl_number_occurences = sum(grepl('alcohol', me_cause, ignore.case = TRUE)))
            )
me_totals_by_county
```